# In 2d, how do I discern when a character is on top of an object, from when it is on the side?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

I am building an auto-run platforming game. I have code so that if the character collides with a wall, they are pushed back until they are able to get past the wall. Unfortunately, this means that when the character tries to jump on an object, he just gets pushed backward.

How do I discern when a character is on top of an object, from when it is on the side?

My Current Algorithm (c-ish because i like c-ish syntax):

```
if(  wall.Top  < (character.Top + character.Height) 
 &&  wall.Left < (character.Left + character.Width) 
 && (wall.Top  + wall.Height) > character.Top 
 && (wall.Left + wall.Width ) > character.Left)
{ 
  #code here# 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that clear what you mean with top and height, but let's say you have your character's x, y, width and height, and so you do for the wall (assuming the x and y values are on the top-left corner of the character/wall, and the y axis gets greater when going downward)

```
if (character.y + character.height > wall.y && charcter.x + character.width > wall.x) {
//collision happening: push character left
}
```

Comment: To explain, I am using properties of Windows Forms Controls in VB.NET. Also, This will activate if the character is below or to the right of the wall.

Comment: No, if the x and y values of the character and wall are taken from the top-left corner of their sprite and the y axis is positive downward.